Need help evaluating a double improper integral
I'm trying to to do the double integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{x^2+1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^4 + y^2} \, dy \, dx
$$
After integrating with respect to $y$, I got:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2}\right) \right) dx
$$
However, I'm finding it difficult to make further progress. I've tried using a change of variables but haven't made any progress. Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed from here

Take $t=\frac1{x}$ and then IBP.

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2}\right) \right) dx=\int_{\infty }^{-\infty } \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(t^2+1\right)-\frac{\pi }{2}\right) , dt=\sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)}\cdot \pi$

@gpmath: $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{x}=t \implies \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dots,dx \mapsto \int\limits_{\color{red}{?}}^{\color{red}{?}}\dots,dt $

@HazemOrabi $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\dots dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\dots dx=\int_{0}^{-\infty}\dots dt+\int_{\infty}^{0}\dots dt=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\dots dt$$
